# UserControl Dependency Property not updating

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have created various UserControls’ that have dependency properties in them. Some update when the property changes and other do not, even though I am sure I have done it correctly.
I have a property in my view model bound to the following property in my user control as follows:

```
<reporting:LegendLabelControl
  Grid.Column="1"
  Grid.Row="3"
  Text="{Binding Path=Item.StatusName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The Text value shows the first time but subsequent update do not reflect change. If I swap this for a TextBlock, the TextBlock does update to it is not an issue with the property.
The dependency property is as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Text", typeof (string), typeof (LegendLabelControl), 
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnTextChanged)
      {
        DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
      });
```

All fairly straight forward and the TextBlock ion the user control is set manually:

```
public string Text
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
  set
  {
    SetValue(TextProperty, value);        
    TxtLabel.Text = value;
  }
}
```

You would think this is fine but it only work the first time. 
Now, my workaround is to remove the dependency property setter so that it thinks it has not been set like this:

```
public string Text
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
  set
  {
    //SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    TxtLabel.Text = value;
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong. I have been working with WPF constantly for a few years and have a handle on most of it but this just stumps me.

Comment: You must not call anything else than SetValue in the setter of a dependency property wrapper. The setter won't be called when the property is set e.g. by a Binding. And you already seem to have OnTextChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you setvalue

```
SetValue(TextProperty, value);
```

Maybe that's over-writing your binding.
Try with the binding mode twoway or setcurrentvalue instead.

As perhaps an aside.
I would avoid using the name of properties which already exist in the framework.
When you register a property name, if it's not unique then bad things can happen.
It's also clearer what you're doing.

Comment: You must call SetValue (and nothing else) in the property setter.

Comment: Great - I never realised that there was SetCurrentValue() method but this does the trick and my property now updates. I appreciate your help. I will also say that I get the point about property names being unique but they are in my UserControl. I wouldn't, however, re-declare an existing property by name.